# Combine Spring Security OAuth with other authentication/authorization capabilities

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-session

Our goal is to design a security strategy to guard an API resource that will be able to handle multiple authentication and authorization patterns/implementations.

The starting point of our journey is Dave Syer's "[Spring Security and AngularJS](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/)" tutorial, which by the way, is a great resource in evaluating different authentication and authorization strategies in modern web development using Spring Security.

For our use case, we decided we need to combine two of the patterns described, namely, the *API Gateway* and the *OAuth SSO*. The reason for doing this is that we have two types of security consumers:

1. *External clients*, which are developed by third party and running in environments that are not under our control. This type of clients is the perfect candidate for the [OAuth SSO](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_sso_with_oauth2_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_v) pattern;
2. *Internal client* that run in our environment and are basically servlet applications that will access the protected resource (API). In this case, we decided to use the *[API Gateway](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_the_api_gateway_pattern_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_iv)* which uses Spring Session under the hood and essentially means that a user http session is shared among multiple servlet containers, which by the way, is a technique that brings a lot of advantages to the table compared to other clustering implementations. The reason for choosing this pattern is that in this way we would be able to remove a lot of the OAuth protocol required chattiness where we really don't need it.

As the development of the POC unfolds, we first notice that both strategies work independently as intended by just using the default configuration pulled in by Spring Boot's auto-configuration capabilities: `@EnableResourceServer` and `@EnableRedisHttpSession`.

The next step in the research was to combine both these in the same application. What we soon found out is that this will not work from the start because each of these will create a separate `SecurityFilterChain` and only one will be chosen by the time a request is made, making that chain exclusive for both types of consumers.

Now we are in the middle of pulling SpringSession's Filter into Spring OAuth's, in this way, we would end up with a single `SecurityFilterChain` that will encompass both strategies.

We know that REST API's should be stateless, but we think this is a good trade off in the case of internal clients where the session is pushed up the stream to the backend API, otherwise, for external clients, the API will remain purely stateless.

The reason we are writing this post is to find out what are community's thoughts on the matter, and what would be the pitfalls of such implementation. We will update the post as our research continues, so please share your thoughts.